# How can I use middleware with interceptor?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, logging, middleware

The middleware is  sufficient for detecting exception request/response but not sufficient for all exception from start point of a process to endpoint. Forexample:

```py
    public class HttpStatusCodeExceptionMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger<HttpStatusCodeExceptionMiddleware> _logger;

        public HttpStatusCodeExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
            _logger = loggerFactory?.CreateLogger<HttpStatusCodeExceptionMiddleware>() ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggerFactory));
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            string message = "";
            try
            {
                await _next.Invoke(context);
            }
           catch (LoginException ex)
            {
                message = ex.Message;

                StackTrace st = new StackTrace(true);
                int num = 0;
                var list = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < st.FrameCount; i++) // 4 frame var

                {

                  ///....
                    list.Add(strBuilder.ToString());

                }

                if (!context.Response.HasStarted)
                {
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                    var response = new ExceptionModel(message);
                    // var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response.getMessage());

                    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(json);
                }
            }
            catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
            {
                message = ex.Message;

                StackTrace st = new StackTrace(true);


                int num = 0;
                var list = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < st.FrameCount; i++) // 4 frame var

                {
                    //.....

                    list.Add(strBuilder.ToString());

                }

                if (!context.Response.HasStarted)
                {
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                    var response = new ExceptionModel(message);
                    // var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response.getMessage());

                    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(json);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```py
everything looks good but if I check error list as json . I can easly said that I can not see throwing error result. At the end and of the day I have to see
all steps of throwing method. 

[
  " Metod: Void MoveNext() File: C:\\Projects\\PlayGround\\Enrichment\\Enrichment\\WebAppEnrichment\\Extensions\\HttpStatusCodeExceptionMiddleware.cs Row: 39 Message 1 : Attempted to divide by zero.",
  " Metod: Void Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine ByRef) File:  Row: 0 Message 2 : Attempted to divide by zero.",
  " Metod: System.Threading.Tasks.Task Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext) File:  Row: 0 Message 3 : Attempted to divide by zero.",
  " Metod: System.Threading.Tasks.Task Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext) File:  Row: 0 Message 4 : Attempted to divide by zero.",
  " Metod: Void MoveNext() File:  Row: 0 Message 5 : Attempted to divide by zero.",
  " Metod: Void Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine ByRef) File:  Row: 0 Message 6 : Attempted to divide by zero.",
  " Metod: System.Threading.Tasks.Task Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext) File:  Row: 0 Message 7 : Attempted to divide by zero.",
  " Metod: System.Threading.Tasks.Task Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext) File:  Row: 0 Message 8 : Attempted to divide by zero.",
  " Metod: System.Threading.Tasks.Task Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext) File:  Row: 0 Message 9 : Attempted to divide by zero.",
  " Metod: System.Threading.Tasks.Task ProcessRequestAsync(Context) File:  Row: 0 Message 10 : Attempted to divide by zero.",
  " Metod: Void MoveNext() File:  Row: 0 Message 11 : Attempted to divide by zero.",
  " Metod: Void Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine ByRef) File:  Row: 0 Message 12 : Attempted to divide by zero.",
  " Metod: System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Boolean] ProcessRequestAsync() File:  Row: 0 Message 13 : Attempted to divide by zero.",
  " Metod: Void MoveNext() File:  Row: 0 Message 14 : Attempted to divide by zero.",
  " Metod: Void Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine ByRef) File:  Row: 0 Message 15 : Attempted to divide by zero.",
  " Metod: System.Threading.Tasks.Task HandleRequest(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext) File:  Row: 0 Message 16 : Attempted to divide by zero.",
  " Metod: Void <HandleRequest>b__26_0(System.Object) File:  Row: 0 Message 17 : Attempted to divide by zero.",
  " Metod: Void RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) File:  Row: 0 Message 18 : Attempted to divide by zero.",
  " Metod: Boolean Dispatch() File:  Row: 0 Message 19 : Attempted to divide by zero."
]
```

HttpStatusCodeExceptionMiddleware.cs Row: 39 Message 1 : Attempted to divide by zero." is not a correct adress. Because it si thrown from last class. I have to see that :
 [image]

Don't worry about method names I am just trying.How can I return see real place happened error not last throtwing place. I created this result by using Microsoft unity interceptor. 
 How can I combine interceptor and middleware together for see deepest detail without writing try-catch shit.Thank you.

Comment: Make a class that inherits the HttpRequest to capture exceptions.

Comment: Add a generic catch block in Invoke:
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        HandleException(context, e, _logger);
    }
 
Which references something like:
    private static void HandleException(HttpContext context, Exception e, ILogger logger)
    {
        string traceid = context.TraceIdentifier;
        logger.LogError(e, $"Error : {traceid}");
        var statusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;  // 500
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)statusCode;
        context.Response.Redirect($"/Error/{traceid.ToLower()}");
    }